# Why is GARCH better?

Tags: standard-deviation, garch

I estimated Value at Risk of a portfolio using 10 years of daily data. The values of VaR I got by three methods is:

```
Histoical    Var-Covar     Garch
 -.02520     -.02487     -0.0177
```

Back testing shows that number of violations in each method are in limits. So my question is that how is GARCH better, like what can I interpret from that number? Does the other two methods overestimate risk?

Answer (score 2):

GARCH is only better if your process is better described as GARCH. The other two methods (in their simplest form) assume that volatility is constant. If your process does not seem to exhibit constant volatility, which is usually the case with equities, then something like GARCH may work better.

The fact that its VaR is lower doesn't mean that it will always be lower than other two methods. It just happened so that the volatility has been lower more recently, so GARCH is forecasting it be lower in near future, hence lower VaR.

You could augment the other two methods with [White's](http://smartquant.com/references/VaR/var32.pdf) scaling or [EWMA](http://value-at-risk.net/exponentially-weighted-moving-average-ewma/) to increase the weight of most recent observations compared to the distant ones. This will have a similar effect, i.e. lower VaR. One could argue that the observations in the distant past are less relevant to the risk today. GARCH does this automatically through its specification.

Comment: It could be added that constancy of conditional variance can be tested using an ARCH-LM test, for example. The test result will indicate whether a GARCH model is relevant. Also, having estimated a GARCH model, its relevance can be tested looking at the standardized residuals (where standardization uses fitted values of conditional variances from the GARCH model) using Li-Mak and other tests.